# Custom Domain => Localhost

Tags: web, dns, localhost

I have a domain name say, `www.example.com`

I am interested in using this domain for development i.e, forward all requests to `localhost`.

I have tried numerous methods like changing my `hosts` file , setting up DNS records, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What did you try **exactly** and what *nothing seems to work* means? What did you test, what error message did you get; what did you expect instead? Also since it is not a programming question this is kind of offtopic here, see maybe instead [su]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing the host file will be the best approach (if external access isn't required).

A typical entry in a host file:
127.0.0.1  example.com

Comment: I tried it , it doesnt work. Do I need any additional settings to make this work?

Answer (score -1):

Apart from changing the host file, you need to add a virtual host in your webserver for the domain name you want to use, and point it to the appropriate directory.

After that you make change in /etc/hosts file pointing the domain to 127.0.0.1

It should work post that.